# Computing explicit solution for PDE with Fourier transform

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I am trying to solve the Dirichlet initial value problem for $0<x<\pi,\mu>0,\nu>0$ for $$u_t=\mu u_{xx}-\nu u_{xxxx}$$ where $u(x,t=0)=\delta(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $u(x=0,t)=u(x=\pi,t)=0$.

In order to solve this, I transformed my solution into Fourier solution and found the complete solution to be $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(-\mu k^2-\nu k^4)t}e^{ikx}e^{-\frac{i\pi k}{2}} dk$$ where the $e^{-\frac{i\pi k}{2}}$ comes from the Fourier transform of the initial condition.

My question is how to solve this integral solution of $u(x,t)$ explicitly?

Comment: Usually, you would complete the square in the exponential term and then integrate the Gaussian. However, [yours seems to be a little tricky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Higher-order_polynomials).

Comment: I do not believe this integral has an explicit solution

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks, thats a little disheartening. I was wondering if you could comment if I calculated the solution correctly in the first place. I hope I didn't make some mistake in my integral?

Comment: @mathim1881, it seems correct to me. The fourth order derivative gives you $k^4$. The integral converges very fast, you can use some Gaussian quadrature for an approximate solution

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks a lot! What exactly does this integral converge to for large time? So as time $t\to\infty$, I am wondering what the expression for the dominant behavior of $u(x,t)$ is. This is much easier to see when I have an explicit solution, but I am not sure how I can understand long time behavior with the integral present.

Comment: @YuriyS From my understanding since the exponential that relies on $t$ goes to $1$, the remaining integral will not converge and so I am confused how you found this?

Comment: Why would the exponential go to one? As time goes to infinity, it will quickly go to zero. For that matter, if you need an asymptotic solution, look up the Laplace method

Comment: Your solution is incorrect, as it does not satisfy the boundary conditions. You should seek a solution in the form of a Fourier series, $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(t)\sin(n x).$